# EasyRec on Heroku?

Tags: mysql, heroku

Is it possible to use Heroku to host Easyrec? I am trying to set up easyrec in the same place as my other stuff which is Heroku.
Basically is there a way to have an mysql database on Heroku?

Comment: Use the ClearDB addon.

Comment: Tried that, unfortunatly you cant create new databases that I could find. Easyrec requires a database named easyrec to be installed